# Cannot login after apache basic to digest change

Tags: apache-2.4, svn

I have a private svn server handled by apache2. I recently read about the difference between AuthType Basic, which I had, and Digest. So I enabled the latter.

But now any attempt at login now asks for a user/password (it didn't before) and then fails without message (it just asks again). And the error.log file shows:

```
[auth_digest:error] [pid 7686] [client 1.2.3.4:38050] AH01790: user `myuser' in realm `Subversion repository' not found: /svn/ProjectX
```

Is there an additional digest configuration that needs to be done somewhere ?

Comment: Please edit the relevant parts from the Apache config into the question.

Comment: I don't know where you read about the differences, but straight from the documentation: `this does not lead to a significant security advantage over basic authentication. On the other hand, the password storage on the server is much less secure with digest authentication than with basic authentication. Therefore, using basic auth and encrypting the whole connection using mod_ssl is a much better alternative.`